# What is the typical access time for reading a 500KB file over a LAN from an NFS v4 server

Tags: io, nfs

Would it be right to compute it as the network time (2ms) + disk seek and block read (10ms) ~= 12ms?
Would that be the correct order of magnitude?

Notes:
 - Using Java.
 - Note that I'm interested in the response time, not absolute rate.
 - Assume mid-range hardware with no caching in place (access pattern is too random for caching to be effective).

Comment: generally correct. Just you have to be sure that rsize/wsize big enough and tcp window size is not too small. And one more thing: do you calkulate the time between open and close or read or write only. NFSv4 has in addition to read/write open and close beeng sent as additional rpc requests.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes.

Without any caching (NFS client cache, server disk cache, disk array cache, SSD), the time to fetch the data from physical disks will be magnitudes bigger than any network latencies (we are talking about local 1 Gbit LAN, which should have <1 ms latency on average). NFS has also read-ahead, so even reading data in small blocks should not affect the latency much.